# How do I display cookies on other pages?

Tags: javascript, cookies

I am learning about cookies and JavaScript for a student project and have attempted to use them in a school project. However, I have stumbled onto a problem when I try to implement a simple function which bookmarks articles.

This is the code which I place in an article. When I press the bookmark icon, the function below is triggered, creating a cookie that expires after 14 days.

```
<script>
function showBookmark() {
        document.getElementById("bookmark").innerHTML = "bookmark";

        var d = new Date();
            d.setTime(d.getTime() + (14*24*60*60*1000));
            var expires = "expires="+ d.toUTCString();
            document.cookie = "cookie1" + "=" + "Article 1 - Title Of Article 1" + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
    };
</script>
```

This is the code which I place in the page where I store and display all the bookmarks the user has made. The code scans through 20 cookies ("cookie1", "cookie2" to "cookie20") and then displays the first 10 cookies where there is a value. The cookies are then displayed in a table using innerHTML().

```
<script>
    function getCookie(cname) {
        var name = cname + "=";
        var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
        var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
        for(var i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
            var c = ca[i];
            while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
                c = c.substring(1);
            }
            if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
                return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
            } else {
                return "false"
            }
        }
    };

    var counter=0;
    for (var alpha=0; alpha<20; alpha++){
        bookmark = getCookie("cookie"+alpha.toString());
        if (counter > 10){
            break;
        }
        if (bookmark != "false"){
            document.getElementById("bookmark"+counter.toString()).innerHTML = bookmark;
            counter++;
        }
    };
</script>
```

However, for some reason the code above does not display the intended result (the name of the article does not appear on the page with all the bookmarks even after pressing the icon and triggering the getCookie function). Is there something wrong with my code?

(This is the first question I am asking so any advice would be greatly appreciated)

Comment: A `return` statement exits from its containing function immediately. You've got `return` statements in your `for` loop, so the loop will only ever execute once.

Comment: Try placing a console.log to see if it is reading the cookies or not.